# MVC + Extjs + IIS6 + Wildcard Mapping = Post Form resulting in 302 object moved

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6, extjs, wildcard-mapping

Everything seems to work fine until i want to submit the form and update the database.

Wildcard mapping works on requests like "/navigation/edit/1", but when i submit the form as:

```
var ajaxPost = function(Url, Params) {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: Url,
            params: Params,
            method: 'POST',
            async: false,
            scope: this
        });
    };
```

it says "200 bad response: syntax error" and in firebug there is "Failed to load source for: http://.../Navigation/edit/1".

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out there was a urlrewrite rule for some other web site corrupting my requests.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its a syntax error: try

```
params: {"sendparams": Params}
```